# How do I make LiveCycle understand HTML tags embedded in XML

Tags: livecycle, livecycle-designer

I am using XML schema to bind data to LiveCycle PDF form.

How do I make LiveCycle understand HTML tags embedded in XML.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague. Typically, we dont use HTML tags contained in XML as they are typically contained in a CDATA tag. Can you please elaborate more and possibly paste sample XML data as well.

Thanks,
Armaghan.

Comment: LiveCycle don't read CDATA tag also. I am trying to embed a XML schema into LiveCycle to generate dynamic data

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help much without getting more information on what you are trying to do. Can you please outline the issue/ your approach in detail with code samples and assets is possible.